# how to access and click react native elements using XPath in appium test framework?

Tags: android, selenium, react-native, appium

I want to access and click react-native button using xpath. I'm using Appium framework for automation testing and running android emulator.

below is my code:

**React-native element:**

```
<Button onPress={ ()=>{this.onPress , Alert.alert("Button Clicked")}}
     title  = "Sign in"
     color="blue"   />
```

**Appium Test File:**

```
expect(await driver.elementsByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text=\'Sign in']")).click();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with React, but why do you have a slash in front of the first single quote in the xpath?

Comment: try driver.elementsByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text=\'Sign in\']")).click(); I think you have to handle both

Comment: @LoflinA it is giving error, click() is not a function.

Comment: I'm not familiar with react-native, but what does expect return, boolean? If it is not a web-element that is being returned, you would not be able to use `click()` method on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using following code with `webdriver.io`

```
const webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
const client = await webdriverio.remote(androidOptions); // you have to specify your android options

const element = await client.findElement('xpath', "//android.widget.TextView[@text='Sign in']");
await client.elementClick(element.ELEMENT);
```